# Spark RDD default number of partitions

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Version: Spark 1.6.2, Scala 2.10

I am executing below commands In the `spark-shell`.
I am trying to see the number of partitions that Spark is creating by default.

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(1 to 10)
println(rdd1.getNumPartitions) // ==> Result is 4

//Creating rdd for the local file test1.txt. It is not HDFS.
//File content is just one word "Hello"
val rdd2 = sc.textFile("C:/test1.txt")
println(rdd2.getNumPartitions) // ==> Result is 2
```

As per the Apache Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/configuration.html), the `spark.default.parallelism` is the number of cores in my laptop (which is 2 core processor).

My question is : `rdd2` seem to be giving the correct result of 2 partitions as said in the documentation. But why `rdd1` is giving the result as 4 partitions ?

Comment: I just observed that when I try to execute the same(val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(1 to 10)) in my IntelliJ IDE project and try to fetch the number of partiotions, I am getting 2 partitions as a result. Not sure why it is giving such a result in spark-shell.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The minimum number of partitions is actually a lower bound set by the `SparkContext`.  Since **spark** uses **hadoop** under the hood, Hadoop [InputFormat`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html) will still be the behaviour by default.

The first case should reflect `defaultParallelism` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e9f983df275c138626af35fd263a7abedf69297f/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L718) which may differ, depending on settings and hardware. (Numbers of cores, etc.)

So unless you provide the number of slices, that **first case** would be defined by the number described by `sc.defaultParallelism`:

```
scala> sc.defaultParallelism
res0: Int = 6

scala> sc.parallelize(1 to 100).partitions.size
res1: Int = 6
```

As for the **second case**, with `sc.textFile`, the number of slices by default is the minimum number of partitions.

Which is **equal to 2** as you can see in [this section of code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e9f983df275c138626af35fd263a7abedf69297f/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2329).

Thus, you should consider the following :

- `sc.parallelize` will take `numSlices` or `defaultParallelism`.
- `sc.textFile` will take the maximum between `minPartitions` and the number of splits computed based on hadoop input split size divided by the block size.

  - `sc.textFile` calls `sc.hadoopFile`, which creates a `HadoopRDD` that uses `InputFormat.getSplits` under the hood [Ref. [InputFormat documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html#getSplits-org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf-int-)].
  - > `InputSplit[] getSplits(JobConf job, int numSplits) throws IOException` : Logically split the set of input files for the job.
    >   Each InputSplit is then assigned to an individual Mapper for processing. 
    >   **Note**: The split is a logical split of the inputs and the input files are not physically split into chunks. For e.g. a split could be  tuple. Parameters: job - job configuration.
    >   numSplits - the desired number of splits, a hint. Returns: an array of InputSplits for the job. Throws: IOException.

**Example:**

Let's create some dummy text files:

```
fallocate -l 241m bigfile.txt
fallocate -l 4G hugefile.txt
```

This will create 2 files, respectively, of size 241MB and 4GB.

We can see what happens when we read each of the files:

```
scala> val rdd = sc.textFile("bigfile.txt")
// rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = bigfile.txt MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:27

scala> rdd.getNumPartitions
// res0: Int = 8

scala> val rdd2 = sc.textFile("hugefile.txt")
// rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = hugefile.txt MapPartitionsRDD[3] at textFile at <console>:27

scala> rdd2.getNumPartitions
// res1: Int = 128
```

Both of them are actually `HadoopRDD`s:

```
scala> rdd.toDebugString
// res2: String = 
// (8) bigfile.txt MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:27 []
//  |  bigfile.txt HadoopRDD[0] at textFile at <console>:27 []

scala> rdd2.toDebugString
// res3: String = 
// (128) hugefile.txt MapPartitionsRDD[3] at textFile at <console>:27 []
//   |   hugefile.txt HadoopRDD[2] at textFile at <console>:27 []
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but is this behavior same when reading the HDFS file using sc.textFile ? Lets say if I am reading the 640MB file in HDFS and input block size is 64MB.

Comment: @Sri textFile uses Hadoop InputFilFormat under the hood, so basically yes, it will be reading partitions by input block.

Comment: [this section of code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e9f983df275c138626af35fd263a7abedf69297f/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2329) sc.textFile uses defaultMinPartitions which is computed as per the logic  def defaultMinPartitions: Int = math.min(defaultParallelism, 2). So as per the code sc.textFile should always give the result as 2 partitions when we do not specify the number of partitions while creating RDD.

Comment: I just created an RDD 'rdd3' for the text file test3.txt without specifying number of partitions. The file size is 241MB.                                                  `scala> val rdd3 = sc.textFile("C:/test3.txt")
scala> rdd3.getNumPartitions
res3: Int = 8` As per the code [this section of code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e9f983df275c138626af35fd263a7abedf69297f/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2329) it should result in 2 partitions always but I see that my rdd3 is created with 8 partiotions. Can you please let me know why is it so ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detail explanation. The results are good as per your statement 
Statement: " sc.textFile will take the maximum between minPartitions and the number of splits computed based on hadoop input split size divided by the block size."

Comment: But I dont see the Spark code in Github [this section of code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e9f983df275c138626af35fd263a7abedf69297f/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2329) supporting this statement.
By looking at the Spark code in Github, I see that sc.textFile use the defaultMinPartitions which is computed as minimum of (defaultParallelism,2).
Spark code: `def defaultMinPartitions: Int = math.min(defaultParallelism, 2)`

Comment: You need to follow the thread of execution which will lead you to HadoopRDD and then getSlices...

Comment: Sorry can you please explain it more clearly, I did not get you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145473/discussion-between-sri-and-eliasah).

Comment: I am still not clear. For 4 GB of file and block size of 128 MB. It should have given 4096/128=32 partitions, no? Why it gave 128 partitions. Also why 8 partitions for 241 MB file? Should it not be 2 partitions?

Comment: @vijayinani input split must be the measure of division, not the block size

Comment: @eliasah I stumbled upon this thread and got confused with the number of partitions created here for a file sized 241 MB. I recreated files such that each record size is 66KB. For a file sized at 255MB, I got 8 partitions whereas for a file sized at 531MB, I got 17 partitions. I'm unable to understand how these partitions values are decided?

Comment: @ Abhash Upadhyaya values of partitions are based on input split size... input split is 32MB, so 255/32~8 and 531/32~17

Comment: I am able to get the same result for 'sc.defaultParallelism' and hence can conclude that the value of this parameter is number of cores of the machine in local mode. But I am not satisfied with the explanation for sc.textFile("..") , it is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Sukumaar what is it that confused you ? "will take the maximum between minPartitions and the number of splits computed based on hadoop input split size divided by the block size."